# Python generate XML with Schema-Location

Tags: python, xml, xsd

How I can create a such XML:

```
<urlset xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    <url>
        <loc>http://...</loc>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

How can I add a xsi:schemaLocation with xml.etree? Here's my code:

```
urlset = ET.Element("urlset")
for url in self.urls:
    url = ET.SubElement(urlset, "url")
    ET.SubElement(url, "loc").text = url.loc
self.tree = ET.ElementTree(urlset)
self.tree.write(path)
```

Is there a simple way to add a such attribute?